# How to spot remove high temp engine paint?

Tags: engine, paint, restoration

I've recently painted an engine post reassembly, due to cost reasons.

No doubt I've encountered overspray on certain parts.  I know sandblasting the engine proper is a huge no-no, and soda blasting sounds like it'd be a pain to eventually paint over again (am I right in thinking that)?

So my real question is, what compound or chemical should I be using to remove mistakes?  I was thinking of using a Qtip to limit over application.

Is there anything purpose built for these kinds of mistakes?

Is aircraft stripper good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is only due to aesthetics, you can use a [Scotch-brite](http://www.cleanitsupply.com/p-32434-scotch-brite-heavy-duty-scour-pad-38-w-x-6-l-green-3pack-mmm223.aspx) pad to remove the excess without chemicals. I take it the engine has not been running yet? If so, the paint is probably not fully cured, so shouldn't be that hard to get off. I would think using chemicals is a bit of overkill for removal. Scotch-brite will take a little bit of elbow-grease, but will strip it down to the metal. If the reason for removal is thinking there will be a mechanical issue, over-spray will not cause any issues.